# How do I modify the value of an element in place in list of lists?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to change the element at position `(row, col)` in `board` which is a list of lists.  The current version which the professor has given us creates a copy and returns it.  Hence, I think it is time consuming:

```
# Add a piece to the board at the given position, and return a new board (doesn't change original)
def add_piece(board, row, col):
    return board[0:row] + [board[row][0:col] + [1,] + board[row][col+1:]] + board[row+1:]
```

To change it in-place, I tried to do (like in the C++ way):

```
def add_piece(board, row, col):
    board[row][col]=1
    return board
```

But this does not modify `board`, I believe, since I get incorrect output.  Could someone please tell me how to change it in-place i.e., to ensure that every time the original `board` itself is modified?  Thank you!

**Edit:**  Apparently, this is not MVC - could someone please point out what needs to be added?  What output I get *is not necessary* since I just want one element at `board[row][col]` to be changed and that is not happening!

Comment: Provide a [MCVE]; inputs, outputs, and desired outputs. "I get an incorrect output" isn't very informative, and your code at present seems correct, so something else is wrong; we don't have enough to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, I am sorry sir, but I think what output I get is irrelevant.  What I want is that only the element at position board[row][col] is changed.  This, I think is pretty Minimal, Complete and Verifiable.  Thank you.

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000, right.  And I want the second one to modify the board.  It would be very helpful if you could point out how I could do it (without returning a new `board` with the modifications).

Comment: Then you will have to declare board a global variable

Comment: Your `add_piece()` code looks correct.  The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Can't we do it the way we do it in C++, `pass by reference`?

Comment: @JohnZwinck, yes, but that is not what I want it to do.  I want it to change the element in-place and return the original `board` (like pass by reference in C++).

Comment: @J.Doe: It **is** pass by reference.  It already is.  Your code is correct already.  It modifies `board` in place.

Comment: Yes, but once it modifies board, board gets deleted because it is a local variable

Comment: @JohnZwinck, oh then do you know why the professor says _(doesn't change original)_?

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 that's simply not true, please be careful about providing misleading information.

Comment: @J.Doe your professor's version doesn't change the original board, it constructs and returns a new board, leaving the original unchanged.  *Your* version ("the C++ way"), *will* change the board you pass as the first argument.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, in the right context.  This is why people are asking for an MCVE.

```
from pprint import pprint

board = [[1,2,3],
         [4,5,6],
         [7,8,9]]

def add_piece(board, row, col):
    board[row][col]=1

add_piece(board,1,1)

pprint(board,width=20)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [4, 1, 6],
 [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Oh, hahaha.. Okay, I got your point.  I was confused why everyone was asking for MCVE.  Thank you.  I appreciate your help.